# How to export iframe display to PDF using ReactJS Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdfrenderer

This is JSX file that I have to display all the email templates and display them with personalized and dynamic content:

```
    <div className="w-[100%] flex justify-between items overflow-x-auto mb-2 flex-col">
                <div>{renderDataTable()}</div>
                <div className="flex flex-row overflow-x-auto w-[95%]">
                    {emailData.map((email: any, index: any) => (
                        <div
                            className="mr-2 bg-[#ededed] rounded-sm p-2 flex flex-col justify-center items-center"
                            key={index}
                        >
                            <h1 className="mb-2 text-[18px] p-2">{email.name}</h1>
                            <div >
                                <iframe
                                    srcDoc={
                                        emailHtmlCodes[index]
                                            ? emailHtmlCodes[index]
                                            : email.htmlCode
                                    }
                                    title={`my-iframe-${index}`}
                                    width={650}
                                    height={600}
                                ></iframe>
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex justify-center items-center mt-2">
                                <button
                                    className="text-white rounded cursor-pointer bg-blue-500 px-4 py-2"
                                >
                                    Print PDF
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
```

I already tried the react-to-print, jsPFD, html2PDF, react-pdf/renderer. But it didnt displayed it properly or the image is not printing.

BTW. I am passing a whole html code content on the (emailHtmlCodes[index]) iFrame srcDoc which is an email template from SFMC and display it to the UI

Comment: This is a little unclear. What is the route of the issue? Do you wish to allow users to see a PDF, download it? Do you have the PDFs already, or do they need generating on the fly from some data, what format is that data? HTML, JSON, Something else? Are you using node to host? What server-side framework are you using? Express, NextJS, something else?

Comment: its an email HTML code, I am passing it on the srcDoc using the iframe. and I want user to be able it to export or download as pdf, not sure if I can use the iframe to display it or just use the emailHtmlCodes which is already the HTML